# Perl - Open large txt file on server and create / save into smaller files of 100 lines each

Tags: arrays, perl, file

I am trying to do this:

1. I FTP a large file of single words (~144,000 and one word per line)
2. I need to open uploaded file and create files with 100 lines max one
   word per line (01.txt, 02.txt etc).
3. I would like the processed 100 to be REMOVED from the original file
   AFTER the file of 100 is created.

The server is shared but, I can install modules if needed.

Now, my code below is very crude as my knowledge is VERY limited. One problem is opening the whole file into an array? The shared server does not sport enough memory I assume to open such a large file and read into memory all at once? I just want the first 100 lines. Below is just opening a file that is small enough to be loaded and getting 100 lines into an array. Nothing else. I typed it quickly so, prob has several issues but, show my limited knowledge and need for help.

```
 use vars qw($Word @Words $IN);
 my $PathToFile = '/home/username/public/wordlists/Big-File-Of-Words.txt';
 my $cnt= '0';
 open $IN, '<', "$PathToFile" or die $!;
 while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    $Word = $_; 
    $Word=~ s/\s//g;
    $Word = lc($Word);
    ######
    if ($cnt <= 99){
        push(@Words,$Word);
    }
    $cnt++;
}
close $IN;
```

Thanks so much.

Okay, I am trying to implement the code below:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
BEGIN {
my $b__dir = (-d '/home/username/perl'?'/home/username/perl':( getpwuid($>) )[7].'/perl');
unshift @INC,$b__dir.'5/lib/perl5',$b__dir.'5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux',map { $b__dir . $_ } @INC;
}
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
print CGI::header();
my $WORD_LIST='/home/username/public/wordlists/Big-File-Of-Words.txt';
sed 's/ *//g' $WORD_LIST | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | split -l 100 -a6 - words.
print 'Done';
1;
```

But I get:

```
syntax error at split-up-big-file.pl line 12, near "sed 's/ *//g'"
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at split-up-big-file.pl line 12.
```

**FINALLY:**
Well I figured out a quick solution that works. Not pretty:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
BEGIN {
my $b__dir = (-d '/home/username/perl'?'/home/username/perl':( getpwuid($>) )[7].'/perl');
unshift @INC,$b__dir.'5/lib/perl5',$b__dir.'5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux',map { $b__dir . $_ } @INC;
}
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use diagnostics;
print CGI::header();
my $sourcefile = '/home/username/public_html/test/bigfile.txt';
my $rowlimit   = 100;
my $cnt= '1';
open(IN, $sourcefile) or die "Failed to open $sourcefile";
my $outrecno = 1;
while(<IN>) {
  if($outrecno == 1) {
  my $filename= $cnt.'.txt';
    open OUT, ">$filename" or die "Failed to create $filename";
      $cnt++;
  }
  print OUT $_;
  if($outrecno++ == $rowlimit) {
    $outrecno = 1;
    close FH;
  }
}
close FH;
```

I found enough info here to get me going. Thanks...

Comment: If you have shell access, you can do this with the command line tool `split` like this: `split -l 100 /home/username/public/wordlists/Big-File-Of-Words.txt` See the man page here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on a slight modification of your code that should work  approximately the way you want it.

It loops through all the lines of the input file and for every 100th line it will write the word list of the words encountered since the last write (or the beginning). The `eof($IN)` check is to catch the remaining lines if they are less than 100.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $PathToFile = '/home/username/public/wordlists/Big-File-Of-Words.txt';

open my $IN, '<', "$PathToFile" or die $!;

my $cnt = 0;
my $cnt_file = 0;
my @Words;

while ( my $Word = <$IN> ) {
    chomp $Word; 
    $Word =~ s/\s//g;
    $Word = lc($Word);
    ######

    push(@Words,$Word);
    if ( !(++$cnt % 100) || eof($IN) ) {
       $cnt_file++;
       open my $out_100, '>', "file_$cnt_file.txt" or die $!;
       print  $out_100 join("\n", @Words), "\n";
       close $out_100;
       @Words = ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a non-Perl solution that you might find interesting...

```
$ split -l 100 -a6 /home/username/public/wordlists/Big-File-Of-Words.txt words.
```

This will split your big file of words into a bunch of files with no more than 100 lines each. The file name will start with `words.`, and the suffix will range from `aaaaaa` to `zzzzzz`. Thus, you'll have `words.aaaaaa`, `words.aaaaab`, `words.aaaaac`, etc. You can then recombine all of these files back into your word list like this:

```
$ cat words.* > reconstituted_word_list.txt
```

Of course, you want to eliminate spaces, and lowercase the words all at the same time:

```
$ WORD_LIST=/home/username/public/wordlists/Big-File-Of-Words.txt
$ sed 's/ *//g' $WORD_LIST | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | split -l 100 -a6 - words.
```

The `tr` is the transformation command, and will change all uppercase to lower case. The `split` splits the files, and `sed` removes the spaces.

One of Unix's big strengths was its file handling ability. Splitting up big files into smaller pieces and reconstituting them was a common task. Maybe you had a big file, but a bunch of floppy disks that couldn't hold more than 100K per floppy. Maybe you were trying to use UUCP to copy these files over to another computer and there was a 10K limit on file transfer sizes. Maybe you were doing FTP by email, and the system couldn't handle files larger than 5K.

Anyway, I brought it up because it's probably an easier solution in your case than writing a Perl script. I am a big writer of Perl, and many times Perl can handle a task better and faster than shell scripts can. However, in this case, this is an easy task to handle in shell.

Comment: W - Thank you. Now for a test drive. Back soon.

Comment: Thank you but, I am unsure how to use this code. Probably is an excellent example but, I do need a solution I can implement in a simple Perl script that I can expand on. I apologize.

Comment: @Student33 This is for Unix. The last example should do everything you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I am understanding. I think. See my appended question and issue I had trying to implement the above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure Perl solution. The problem is that you want to create files after every 100 lines.

To solve this, I have two loops. One is an infinite loop, and the other loops 100 times. Before I enter the inner loop, I create a file for writing, and write one word per line. When that inner loop ends, I close the file, increment my `$output_file_num` and then open another file for output.

A few changes:

- I use `use warnings;` and `use strict` (which is included when you specify that you want Perl version 5.12.0 or greater).
- Don't use `use vars;`. This is obsolete. If you have to use package variables, declare the variable with `our` instead of `my`. When should you use package variables? If you have to ask that question, you probably don't need package variables. 99.999% of the time, simply use `my` to declare a variable.
- I use `constant` to define your word file. This makes it easy to move the file when needed.
- My `s/../../` not only removes beginning and ending spaces, but also lowercases my word for me. The `^\s*(.*?)\s*$` removes the entire line, but captures the word sans spaces at the beginning and end of the word. The `.*?` is like `.*`, but is *non-greedy*. It will match the minimum possible (which in this case does not include spaces at the end of the word).
- Note I define a label `INPUT_WORD_LIST`. I use this to force my inner last to exit the outer loop.
- I take advantage of the fact that `$output_word_list_fh` is defined only in the loop. Once I leave the loop, the file is automatically closed for me since `$output_word_list_fh` in out of scope.

And the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.12.0;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant WORD_FILE => "/home/username/public/wordlists/Big-File-Of-Words.txt";

open my $input_word_list_fh, "<", WORD_FILE;

my $output_file_num = 0;

INPUT_WORD_LIST:
for (;;) {
    open my $output_word_list_fh, ">", sprintf "%05d.txt", $output_file_num;
    for my $line (1..100) {
        my $word;
        if ( not $word = <$input_word_list_fh> ) {
            last INPUT_WORD_LIST;
        }
        chomp $word;
        $word =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/\L$1\E/;
        say {$output_word_list_fh} "$word";
    }
    close $output_word_list_fh;
    $output_file_num += 1;
}
close $input_word_list_fh;
```

Comment: This one just gives me a 500 server error. I added use warnings;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser); but, no printing just 500 internal server error.

Comment: I didn't set this up as a CGI process. You didn't mention it in your original file. The attempt to write to the disk could cause the error.